# IIS resource request filtering ASP.NET Web API

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, authorization, http-get

I am building a ASP.Net Web API as back-end and AngularJS as front-end website, and hosting it on IIS 10. User are allowed to upload files to `Uploads` folder, but User can only download certain files with `Authorization header on HTTP GET` from `Uploads` folder, and I request filtering denied access to `Uploads` directory so that user can't simply HTTP GET any resources from `Uploads` folder bypass authorization. The question is what if I want to show certain images from `Uploads` folder on my website, on html? I could not `HTTP GET` any resources from `Uploads` folder. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: This is a pretty badly written question, without seeing more about your specific issue and maybe some code this is hard to answer. How is the upload happening? When you say 'request filtering denied' what do you mean, how are you implementing this? More info, more info!!

Comment: @matt_lethargic IIS Request Filtering, it allows you to denied public access to certain directory

Comment: So you're essentially just browsing to the uploads folder? If you want to get an uploaded file would you not create a HttpGet endpoint that downloads any files, this way you can control the security in the API and not in IIS

Comment: @matt_lethargic ya but what if I want to show images from that uploads folder, using <IMG src> tag? My Web API only authorize with web token, I can't attach authorization header to HTML tag